# Some Admin Labels changed to german in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm not sure what happened but recently, my admin options for all the words for yes and no changed to german with nein and ja. I'm trying to find out where to go to change the locale settings for yes and no back to english

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have probably selected *German* in bottom left language chooser in the admin panel (that is a language chooser for admin panel).

Change that to *English* and it will remember your choice.